# Why is my neural network function approximation sensitive to seed?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, random-seed

I would like to approximate the terminal pay-off of a call option by a neural network using the following code:

```
import torch
import DGM_torch as DNM
torch.manual_seed(12)

# Terminal pay-off call option
def Phi(S):
    return torch.max(torch.tensor(0.0), S - 1.0)

DNM_model = DNM.DGMNet(layer_width=50, input_dim=1) # Set up network 
nSim = 600                                          # Number of samples
S_high = 2.0

# Train  network
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(DNM_model.parameters(), 1e-3) # Define the optimizer with an initial learning rate
for j in range(100):    
    S = torch.rand([nSim,1]) * S_high
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.mean((DNM_model(S) - Phi(S))**2)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

where DNM_model is a Long short-term memory model with three layers. Somehow setting the seed to 12 works but setting it to 11 the network always returns 0, but why? I would think that it is not very difficult for a network to learn such a function and the network returning zero gives a large loss.